# Why would my app undo changes made to its appname.exe.config file?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an WPF application that allows the user to select from one of several environment-specific .config files.  I'm accomplishing this by deploying copies of each .config file and simply file copying the selected environment's config file on top of the existing appname.exe.config file, then using the ConfigurationManager to refresh the sections that have changed (just appSettings in this case).  All is good, and I've confirmed that the operation really does overwrite the config with the correct environment version.

However, when I exit the WPF application, the configuration file reverts to it's original version.  I've confirmed that this behavior does not happen with a WinForms app and a console app that performs the same type of .config file manipulation.  I've also confirmed that my config file copying code is not being re-executed unexpectedly.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: That's not `vanilla` behavior. It does not happen in any of the many WPF application we have in production. Post the relevant code.

Comment: I've extracted the relevant code to a new project and confirmed that the behavior does NOT repeat, so I agree that it's not vanilla behavior.  Unfortunately I am unable to post more of the original project as it's proprietary info.  I'll start narrowing down a limited subset of functionality that causes the behavior and see if I can reach something that both doesn't work and is not private.  By then I'll probably see a cause/solution, but I appreciate your direction and confirmation so far.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: This only seems to happen when running the app within Visual Studio (2013).  If I run the compiled app from the bin/debug/ folder, it behaves correctly and the .config file remains changed.

Comment: that behavior is by design.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: Also confirmed that the app works correctly within VS if I start without the debugger.

Comment: it's got nothing to do with "undo" anything. Visual Studio keeps the config file from the `bin` folder in sync with the config file from the project.

Answer (score 0):

that behavior is by design.

When running the application from the IDE, Visual Studio copies the `.config` file from the project to the `bin` folder (or whereever you're outputting your project to).

You will have to avoid messing with the config file when in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the behavior your talking about... I'll do some research on why this would be a desirable behavior.

Comment: I've yet to find anything that supports this happening when the app is shutting down.